# MySQL+Python on Raspbian produces Syntax Error

Tags: python, mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am now starting to use Python scripts to manage databases in association with MySQL.

I am facing an issue of Syntax error and can't seem to figure out why.

When i run the following code:

```
import MySQLdb
import time
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","username","password","DataBase")
c= conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
rows=c.fetchall()
for eachRow in rows:
print eachRow
```

I can get the rows in my table so everything is fine.
However when i use the INSERT statment as follows:

```
import MySQLdb
import time
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","username","password","DataBase")
c= conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) VALUES(23:EA:4A:7F:A1,Someone)")
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
rows=c.fetchall()
for eachRow in rows:
print eachRow
```

I get a syntax error

> "near 'Column1,column2) Values(23:EA:4A:7F:A1,Someone)' at line 1"

I have checked the documentation and believe I am using the right syntax.
Have tried using multiple field types (varchar, text,...) and with semicolon at the end or not.

- column1 is of type varchar(14)
- column1 is of type text

Using mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.57 for debian-linux-gnu (armv71)

Comment: Try putting quotes around values

Comment: Not related to your INSERT issue:  your final `print` statement inside the `for` loop should be *indented*, preferably by 4 spaces.  Indentation is important in Python.  Also, your `print` indicates you are using the old python 2, in which case you should tag it as such in a SO question (the default tag assumes python 3).

Comment: @fodma1 No luck with that, tried with the space between tablename and paranthesis and still same error.

Comment: @Don no luck adding quotes, still same error

Comment: @cdarke ty for the heads up, not used to asking questions about coding, I'm starting to lear now :)

Comment: What if you run the INSERT in MySQL shell?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
INSERT INTO "table" (column1, column2) VALUES('23:EA:4A:7F:A1','Someone')
```

`table` is a reserved keyword in SQL, so you should avoid naming your table `table`. It's like naming your kid `Kid`, oh wait.. But anyway if you are planning to use reserved keywords, you have to wrap them in double quotes.

As for the values, `Someone` is a string, so you should definitely wrap it in single quotes. I'm not sure about the type of `23:EA:4A:7F:A1`, but I guess that's also a string, so better wrap that too.